# await DisplayAlert answer when using OnBackButtonpressed() for user confimation

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

I would like to use the `OnBackButtonPressed()` build in function of Xamarin Forms to either navigate them to the MainPage or keeping them at the current page uppon answering a `DisplayAlert()`.

The problem is that i am not able to await for the answer (in this case `OnAlertYesNoClicked();`) when `OnBackButtonPressed()` is called upon, and since the default value of a bool is `false` it will just close the application.

Is there any way to use the users answer as bool for `OnBackButtonPressed()` ?

Example:

```
    bool action;
    async public void OnAlertYesNoClicked()
    {
        bool action = await DisplayAlert("Question?", "Are you sure you want to go back? Your result wont be saved!", "Yes", "No");
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        OnAlertYesNoClicked();
        if(action == true)
        {
            Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage(), true);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way to override hardware back button and show a confirmation dialog box to user.

```
 protected  override  bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        //return base.OnBackButtonPressed();

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            var result = await this.DisplayAlert("Question?", "Are you sure you want to go back? Your result wont be saved!", "Yes", "No");
            if (result) await this.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page14()); // or anything else

        });


        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

What’s happening is that the check is happening before the value is changed based on the user input. So you want to base the check on the user input directly.

In order to do that, instead of writing what you wrote, you might want to do this instead:

```
public async Task<bool> OnAlertYesNoClicked()
{
    return await DisplayAlert("Question?", "Are you sure you want to go back? Your result wont be saved!", "Yes", "No");
}

protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    if(OnAlertYesNoClicked().Result())
    ...
```

It is preferred not to use .Result() to get the response but you can’t change OnBackButtonPressed to return Task instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it seems Cherry Bu has found a solution for me!

Comment: No problem. That one is better :)