# MAUI.NET display a pop up on back button pressed

Tags: c#, maui

I'm trying to display a popup when the user hits the back button in a MAUI app.

I'm finding it tricky as the DisplayAlert is an asynchronous method that's needs to be awaited, but the override for OnButtonPressed is synchronous.

If I try and dispatch the alert in a separate awaitable task, it will show. But the App will still navigate away as it's not awaiting it.

I can't see any way to override the OnButtonPressed asynchronously.

Ideally I'm trying to do something like this:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    var leave = await DisplayAlert("Leave lobby?", "Are you sure you want to leave the lobby?", "Yes", "No");

    if (leave)
    {
        await handleLeaveAsync();
        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: you should be able to add `async` to `OnButtonPressed`

Comment: When I make the override async, I have to change the return type signature to Task<bool>

If I do that, then I get CS0508 "LobbyPage.OnBackButtonPressed() return type must be 'bool' to match overridden member Page.OnBackButtonPressed()"

Comment: sorry, that trick does work on voids.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61190662/await-displayalert-answer-when-using-onbackbuttonpressed-for-user-confimation or https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a9712615-a13e-4b92-8320-2397f4330ce0/how-do-you-properly-implement-a-onbackbuttonpressed-override-with-async-functions?forum=xamarinforms

Comment: Ok this seems to work, I think I'm just used to other frameworks as I'd expect to reuse the behaviour of base.OnBackButtonPressed

`protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
    {
        var leave = await DisplayAlert("Leave lobby?", "Are you sure you want to leave the lobby?", "Yes", "No");

        if (leave)
        {
            await handleLeaveAsync();
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
        }
    });

    return true;
}`

This does the job however :) Thanks!

Comment: When you solve a problem, so that it is easier for others to find the solution in the future, please add `Your Answer` below (instead of in a comment). Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I'll add a answer with the working code and edit the comment. I was hoping for a few more alternatives and insight as it still doesn't feel right. But C'est la vie!

Answer (score 5):

Thanks @Jason for posting a link to similar problem in Xamarin, this works in MAUI and will stop the page from navigating away, however with this implementation we're unable to use the base behaviour.

This may be a problem if you rely on your navigation history as you now instruct the app where to navigate if they confirm, you will require more code to preserve and retrieve the history to navigate back to the previous screen.

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () => 
    { 
        var leave = await DisplayAlert("Leave lobby?", "Are you sure you want to leave the lobby?", "Yes", "No"); 
        
        if (leave) 
        { 
            await handleLeaveAsync(); 
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage()); 
        } 
    }); 
    
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Changing `await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());` to `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");` should accomplish the same thing and retain the navigation history.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to preserve the original navigation history, so I did the following for an app using `Shell` navigation:

```
private void EditPage_Disappearing(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Shell.Current.Navigating -= Current_Navigating;
}

private void EditPage_Appearing(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Shell.Current.Navigating += Current_Navigating;
}

async private void Current_Navigating(object? sender, ShellNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CanCancel)
    {
        e.Cancel(); // Cancel original back navigation to allow for prompt to show

        if (await DisplayAlert("Ignore changes", "Are you sure you want to leave without saving changes?", "Yes", "No"))
        {
            Shell.Current.Navigating -= Current_Navigating; // Avoid infinite confirmation loop

            await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopAsync(); // Go back
        }
    }
}
```